# scheme how do you sum numbers in a list when you have structures and list of lists

Tags: scheme, racket

```
;; An ATOM is one of: 
;; -- Symbol
;; -- String 
;; -- Number

;; An SEXP (S-expression) is one of: 
;; -- empty 
;; -- (cons ATOM SEXP)
;; -- (cons SEXP SEXP)
```

So i'm trying to sum up all the numbers in SEXP! Here's my code,

```
;; sum-numbers: sexp -> Number

(define (sum-numbers sexp)
(cond 
  [(empty? sexp) 0]
  [(ATOM? (first sexp)) (+ (atom-sum-numbers (first sexp))
                           (sum-numbers (rest sexp)))]
  [(SEXP? (first sexp)) (+ (sum-numbers (first sexp))
                           (sum-numbers (rest sexp)))]))

;; atom-sum-numbers: Atom -> Number 
(define (atom-sum-numbers a)
    (cond 
       [(symbol? a) 0]
       [(number? a) (+ (ATOM-number a)
                    (atom-sum-numbers a))]
       [(string? a) 0]))
```

However, an error says `cond`: all question results were false. I'm wondering what happened there.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html). When you write `(define-struct ATOM (symbol string number))` you're saying that an `ATOM` is the _combination_ of three elements: a symbol, a string and a number - not just one of them!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez What the OP seemed to have wanted is something akin to C's unions. I don't know if any Scheme implementation supports unions though; that seems memory-unsafe. Of course, statically-typed languages have concepts like algebraic data types, but again, this doesn't apply to Scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing struct accessor procedures with list manipulation procedures, that won't work - you have to be consistent, if using structs then you must use the struct's own procedures.

Also, your `ATOM` structure looks wrong, as it is, it's saying: an atom is made up of a symbol, a string *and* a number (the three things, not just one of them!). Of course, the `symbol?`, `number?` and `string?` predicates won't work for that struct, that's why `cond` is complaining that all of the conditions are false.

I suggest you try something else, where the atoms are really *atoms*, not structs. Otherwise you'll have to rethink the `ATOM` structure, in its current form won't work in the way you imagine. For instance, this will work:

```
(define (sum-numbers sexp)
  (cond 
    [(empty? sexp) 0]
    [(SEXP? (SEXP-ATOM sexp)) (+ (sum-numbers (SEXP-ATOM sexp))
                                 (sum-numbers (SEXP-SEXP sexp)))]
    [else (+ (atom-sum-numbers (SEXP-ATOM sexp))
             (sum-numbers (SEXP-SEXP sexp)))]))

(define (atom-sum-numbers a)
  (cond 
    [(symbol? a) 0]
    [(number? a) a]
    [(string? a) 0]))
```

Let's test it, and notice how atoms are plain Scheme atoms, not instances of the `ATOM` struct:

```
(sum-numbers 
 (make-SEXP 'x 
            (make-SEXP 7
                       (make-SEXP "a" 
                                  '()))))
=> 7
```

Comment: thanks! I was wondering if ATOM should be a structure or not. In this case, ATOM is just flat. So i'm thinking in this case, we need to write ATOM? function which identify whether it is an ATOM and SEXP? whether it is an SEXP.

Comment: Also, SEXP should be a list not a structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;; atom? : Any -> Boolean 
 ;; true if input is an Atom false otherwise 
 (define (atom? at) 
   (or (number? at)
       (symbol? at)
       (string? at)))

 ;; sexp? : Any -> Boolean 
 ;; true if input is n Sexp, false otherwise 
 (define (sexp? s) 
   (or
     (empty? s)
     (and (cons? s) 
          (atom? (first s))
          (sexp? (rest s)))
     (and (cons? s)
          (sexp? (first s))
          (sexp? (rest s)))))

 ;; sum-numbers: sexp -> Number
 ;; given a sexp returns the sum of all the Numbers in the list

 ;; sum-numbers: Sexp -> Number
 (define (sum-numbers sexp)
   (cond 
     [(empty? sexp) 0]
     [(atom? (first sexp)) (+ (atom-sum-numbers (first sexp))
                              (sum-numbers (rest sexp)))]
     [(sexp? (first sexp)) (+ (sum-numbers (first sexp))
                              (sum-numbers (rest sexp)))]))


 ;; atom-sum-numbers: anything(symbol number or string) -> Number
 ;; if the given is a number, add it 

 (define (atom-sum-numbers a)
   (cond 
     [(symbol? a) 0]
     [(number? a) a]
     [(string? a) 0]))
```