# scheme replace a1 in a list of lists with a2, both a1 a2 is flat

Tags: scheme, racket

Going further for the [scheme how do you sum numbers in a list when you have structures and list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747178/scheme-how-do-you-sum-numbers-in-a-list-when-you-have-structures-and-list-of-lis/26755096#26755096) now i want to replace all occurrences of atom a1 in SEXP with atom a2.

For example,

```
(replace (list (list 'a 'b) (list 1 3 )) 'a 'b) =>
(list (list 'b 'b) (list 1 3))

(replace (list (list 'a 'b) (list 1 3)) 1 2) =>
(list (list 'a 'b) (list 2 3))

;; An ATOM is one of: 
;; -- Symbol
;; -- String 
;; -- Number

(define-struct SEXP (ATOM SEXP))

;; An SEXP (S-expression) is one of: 
;; -- empty 
;; -- (cons ATOM SEXP)
;; -- (cons SEXP SEXP)
```

My code,

```
;; replace: Atom atom sexp -> sexp

(define (replace a1 a2 sexp)
   (cond
      [(empty? sexp) empty]
      [(SEXP? sexp)
             (cons (replace a1 a2 (first sexp)) (replace a1 a2 (rest sexp)))]
      [else
         (cond 
             [(or (symbol=?  (first sexp) a1)
                  (string=?  (first sexp) a1)
                  (=  (first sexp)  a1))
              (cons a2 (replace a1 a2 (rest sexp)))]
             [else (cons (first sexp) (replace a1 a2 (rest sexp)))])]))
```

for the part to determine if it is a1, do we need call a helper function we could do so in my way present here?

Also, since sexp is a list of lists and atom is flat,

```
 (symbol=?  (first sexp) a1)
```

might cause problem since scheme would expect a symbol but given (list xxxxxx)

How do you fix that problem as well?

Comment: Are you using Racket? if so, please add the corresponding tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be simplified a great deal if we make sure that the equality comparison is performed only when we're sure that `sexp` is an atom, try this:

```
(define (replace a1 a2 sexp)
  (cond
    [(empty? sexp) empty]
    [(SEXP? sexp) ; (define SEXP? pair?)
     (cons (replace a1 a2 (first sexp))
           (replace a1 a2 (rest  sexp)))]
    [(equal? sexp a1) a2]
    [else sexp]))
```

The same comments to your previous question apply, though: you must be consistent, and if you're using `SEXP` structs then you must stick to using that struct's accessor procedures, instead of `first`, `rest`, etc. Also notice how we can use `equal?` for comparisons when we don't know beforehand the specific type of the elements. Test it like this, and notice the correct order of the parameters:

```
(replace 'a 'b (list (list 'a 'b) (list 1 3)))
=> '((b b) (1 3))

(replace 1 2 (list (list 'a 'b) (list 1 3)))
=> '((a b) (2 3))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, test does not give the expected result.

Comment: @pnixsweet which test? what's my result, what's the expected result?

Comment: @pnixsweet also remember that `(list (list 'b 'b) (list 1 3))` is the same as `'((b b) (1 3))`

Comment: (replace 'a 'b (list (list 'a 'b) (list 1 3))) => (list (list 'a 'b) (list 1 3))

Comment: @pnixsweet It's working for me. how did you define `SEXP?` ? try replacing `SEXP?` with `pair?`

Comment: @pnixsweet Once again: you’re mixing structs with lists. If you build your input data using `list`, then you can not use `SEXP?`, you have to use `pair?`. You can only use `SEXP?` if you build the input with `make-SEXP`, as shown in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: `;; los-atom-occurs? : LOS Atom -> Boolean
;; does the atom occur in los?
(define (los-atom-occurs? los a)
  (cond [(empty? los) false]
        [(cons? los) (or (atom-occurs? (first los) a)
                         (los-atom-occurs? (rest los) a))]))`

Comment: @pnixsweet Did my answer work after replacing `SEXP?` with `pair?` ? your questions were a bit confusing, first you started asking about structs and then suddenly they were lists all along  :/

Comment: pretty much my bad. First i thought ATOM and SEXP are structures. But the fact that ATOM is flat and SEXP is list of lists after all. I haven't try the pair yet. Will let you know.

Comment: @pnixsweet ok! but it's `pair?` <- with a `?` at the end.

Comment: @i think cons? might suit better. After doing that, the result is correct now. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: @pnixsweet yep, `cons?` will also work. I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: now i think we need reshape the problem i asked on another thread.

Comment: @pnixsweet Fair enough. Please don't forget to accept this answer, if it was helpful for you ;)